# NumberSequence - Dynamics ax 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I need help.

I'm trying to add a few auto-generated number sequences in my tables. I'm doing it by using         `loadModule()` in Class `NumberSeqModuleMine`:

```
NumberSeqDatatype datatype = NumberSeqDatatype::construct();
datatype.parmDatatypeId(extendedtypenum(IdStuffSeq));
datatype.parmReferenceHelp(literalstr("@SYS32633"));
datatype.parmWizardIsContinuous(true);
datatype.parmWizardIsManual(NoYes::No);
datatype.parmWizardIsChangeDownAllowed(NoYes::No);
datatype.parmWizardIsChangeUpAllowed(NoYes::No);
datatype.parmWizardHighest(99999);
datatype.parmWizardLowest(1);
datatype.parmSortField(12);
this.create(datatype);

datatype.parmDatatypeId(extendedtypenum(IdOrderSeq));
datatype.parmReferenceHelp(literalstr("@SYS32674"));
datatype.parmWizardIsContinuous(true);
datatype.parmWizardIsManual(NoYes::No);
datatype.parmWizardIsChangeDownAllowed(NoYes::No);
datatype.parmWizardIsChangeUpAllowed(NoYes::No);
datatype.parmWizardHighest(99999);
datatype.parmWizardLowest(1);
datatype.parmSortField(12);
this.create(datatype);
```

Next I've created a job and execute it:

```
static void jobName(Args _args){
NumberSeqModuleMine  NumberSeqModuleMine = new NumberSeqModuleMine();
NumberSeqModuleMine.loadModule();
```

Next in all tables I have metodls like this:

```
static client server NumberSequenceReference numRefIdOrderSq(){
return NumberSeqReference::findReference(extendedTypeNum(IdOrderSeq)); }
```

My question: I added all numbers without `IdOrderSeq` however I used the same methods like in other `SeqNumbers` - have you got idea what I'm doing wrong so only one number isn't working?

EDIT - Ok... As I noticed by testing my aplication NumberSequence is working but not always - sometimes Dynamics set the number but sometimes it leaves blank field in base. But I don't know this is server issue, my form problem or something else. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing all caches, in particular run this code:

```
NumberSeqApplicationModule::loadAll();
SysGlobalObjectCache::clearAllCaches();
appl.numberSeqGlobal().buildModulesMap();
```

Or restart AX, and if all fails, restart the AOS as well.

See also [Using the Enhanced Number Sequence Framework (White paper)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272879.aspx)

> Note: In Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009, number sequence references could be initialized 
>   by restarting the Application Object Server (AOS). In Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012, the 
>   initialization of references to populate the NumberSequenceDatatype and 
>   NumberSequenceParameterType tables has moved to the initialization checklist. To
>   initialize the newly created references, run a job that executes the LoadModule
>   method.
>
> You can also reinitialize all references by running a job that executes the LoadAll
>   method in the NumberSequenceModuleSetup class. However, for reinitializing all 
>   references, you must ensure that there are no existing number sequences already 
>   defined in the system..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the sort field of IdOrderSeq to e.g. 13? I think each number in a module needs its own sorting number. To be clear, I'm talking about the following line of code:

`datatype.parmSortField(12)`

Comment: Hi Jaszym, please try synchronizing the data dictionary after you've don this. The DD sync is responsible for loading those modules so it might help.